# How should I reduce this react native code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, attributes

I am developing a react native application in which i need a lot of text-input fields.
So as you can see below i am using this "TextInputMask" field `import { TextInputMask } from "react-native-masked-text";`

```
<Text>Field Title</Text>
<TextInputMask
  multiline={true}
  type={"money"}
  options={{
    precision: 0,
    separator: ".",
    delimiter: ",",
    unit: "£",
    suffixUnit: "",
  }}
  style={globalstyles.input}
  textAlign={"center"}
  placeholder={"£500"}
  keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
  value="Value of the field"
  onChangeText={(maskedText, rawText) => {
    functionName(rawText);
  }}
/>
```

In other fields i am repeating again and again these attributes:

```
  multiline={true}
  type={"money"}
  options={{
    precision: 0,
    separator: ".",
    delimiter: ",",
    unit: "£",
    suffixUnit: "",
  }}
  style={globalstyles.input}
  textAlign={"center"}
  placeholder={"£500"}
  keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
```

My question is, is possible to make an object or something where i will store all the repeating attributes? so i can just pass that to the other fields.

Comment: Yes, create a function and return an array of react components. Their props is based on the function params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just create a wrapper component

```
const MyTextInputMask = ({value, onChangeText}) => {
  return <TextInputMask
    multiline={true}
    type={"money"}
    options={{
      precision: 0,
      separator: ".",
      delimiter: ",",
      unit: "£",
      suffixUnit: "",
    }}
    style={globalstyles.input}
    textAlign={"center"}
    placeholder={"£500"}
    keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
  />
}
```

and then use it and just send the value and the onChange function

```
<MyTextInputMask 
  value="Value of the field"
  onChangeText={(maskedText, rawText) => {
    functionName(rawText);
  }}
/>
```